# Android always takes my layouts from v9 folder even when running other versions

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a little problem.

I've created a layout folder layout-v9 and in the layoutfolder I've got 2 layouts. In my ordinary layout folder I've got the same 2 layouts.

Now when running Android 4.4 he still takes the layout from the v9 folder.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`layout-v9` folder won't be used only by Android API 9, but by every Androd with API >= 9, it's why Android 4.4 (API 19) uses it.

[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

> The API level supported by the device. For example, v1 for API level 1
>   (devices with Android 1.0 or higher) and v4 for API level 4 (devices
>   with Android 1.6 or higher). See the Android API levels document for
>   more information about these values.

EDIT:

> How can I have a layout for just the v9 versions?

I don't know about other way using folders than also providing `v10` folder, so API 9 will use `v9` folder, and any higer API `v10` folder.

In case of other problems, beside using folders, you may want to do some things related to API >= 10 in code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
     // API >= 10 stuff
}
```

Comment: How can I have a layout for just the v9 versions?

Comment: Thanks that helped. I've renamed the layout folder to layout-v10.